# coreplot sync several subview

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot

I'm using core plot and I have for subview graphs in the same view. Is it possible to "link" the subviews so that when I drag one of the drags to the left then the other graphs move as well and stay aligned?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a plot space delegate to monitor changes to the plot space (drag and/or zoom) and make corresponding changes to the other graph. If the link goes both ways, use a flag or some other mechanism to ensure that you don't end up in an infinite loop of changes to one graph bouncing back and forth between the delegates.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any sample OBJ-C code for this. I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: I don't have any sample code handy. I would implement the `-plotSpace:didChangePlotRangeForCoordinate:` delegate method for each plot space you want to monitor. Use `-plotRangeForCoordinate:` to read the new plot range from the plot space parameter. Use that to compute the desired range for the other plot space and call `-setPlotRange:forCoordinate:` to update the range.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes

Comment: HI, I cannot find the second and third delegate methods that you mention. Can you please tell me what delegate header(s) I should include in my .h file? I am coding in OBJ-C. Thanks.

Comment: `-plotRangeForCoordinate:` and `-setPlotRange:forCoordinate:` are [`plot space`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_plot_space.html) methods.

Comment: thanks. do you provide any one on one consulting for a fee?  I could use the help. Thanks.

Comment: No, but I probably should. You're not the first to ask. :-)

Comment: Please let me know if you decide to do it. I'd love to pay to pick your brain for an hour, or so. Thanks.